# If $x^2\equiv a\pmod n$, then $(n-x)^2\equiv a\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

> Given that $x$ is a solution to $x^{2}\equiv a \pmod n$, show that $y=n-x$ is also a solution.

Please don't solve, just give me a hint.

Comment: Carry on the calculation $\;(n-x)^2\pmod n\;$ , that's all !

Comment: Note that using the command `a \pmod n` drastically simplified the formatting necessary, and produced a nicer-looking result :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Expand $y^2 = (n - x)^2$ modulo $n$.

(This approach is perhaps easier to see intuitively if we recall that $$n - x \equiv -x \bmod n,$$ in which case we can write $$(-x)^2 \equiv a \bmod n,$$ which bears a close resemblance to the real analogue of the statement.)

Comment: Is it right to write $x^2\pmod {n}\equiv a\pmod n$

Comment: I don't think I've seen it written that way, and it's anyway redundant so I'd probably avoid it.

Comment: So the answer $y^{2}=(n-x)^{2}=(-x \pmod{n})^{2}=x^{2}\pmod{n}^2=a\pmod{n}\pmod{n}^2=a\pmod{n}$ is that right?

Comment: It's the right idea, but the notation is peculiar: The notation $\pmod n$ is just a reminder that we're working modulo $n$, and in particular, one shouldn't "square" it or otherwise apply algebraic operations to it. I would just write this as $$y^2 \equiv (n - x)^2 \equiv (-x)^2 \equiv x^2 \equiv a \bmod{n}.$$

Comment: how did you get $(n-x)^{2}=(-x)^2$, shouldn't that be $(n-x)^{2}=(-x \pmod n)^{2}$?

Comment: The statement is that they are equivalent modulo $n$, not equal---this is encoded by the use of $\equiv$ (instead of $=$) and the notation $\bmod n$ at the end of the equation. We could write that particular equivalence as $$(n - x)^2 \equiv (-x)^2 \bmod n$, but again, we shouldn't "square" $\bmod n$---think of it just as a mark we make at the end of a line to denote that the equation holds modulo $n$, and not as an algebraic object that can be manipulated in its own right.

Comment: I get it now, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand $y^2=(n-x)^2$ and fill in the expression. The rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ n\!:\ \color{#c00}{\overbrace{n\!-\!x}^{\large n \color{black}{ \,\equiv\,0}}\equiv -x}\Rightarrow (\color{#c00}{n\!-\!x})^2\equiv (\color{#c00}{-x})^2 \equiv x^2 \equiv a\ $ by   [basic Congruence Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, by the linked congruence rules, congruences are preserved by replacing arguments of sums and products by any congruent argument.